# In the Bixby Simulator tv view is the image with the minaret configurable?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

In the Bixby Simulator tv view is the image with the minaret configurable?[image]  where does this image come from? is it a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This image is not customizable. It is a placeholder for whatever content the user would be viewing on their TV when they invoke Bixby.